# evaluate string to modify data model in ruby

Tags: ruby

I seem to be running into a problem with Rails 3 and I can't seem to figure it out. 
Here's what I am trying to do:

```
att1 = "column"
att2 = "1"
final_column = "#{att1}_#{att2}"

obj.final_column = 4
  ====> Error
  -----> NoMethodError: undefined method `final_column=' for class....
```

If I do this it works though:

> ```
> obj.column1=4
> ```

What can I do to my final_column to make it work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
obj.send("#{final_column}=", 4)
```

If you want to respect the private/protected visibliy, use `public_send` instead of `send`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I wanted to avoid using the dot notation and this works. Do you know if there's any down side?

Comment: @MarcoA The one potential gotcha is that `send` bypasses `private`/`protected` visibility, so it's possible to call a method that you wouldn't otherwise be able to.

Comment: It can be confusing and error prone. Also, you don't want to use strings that comes from the browser or any user input. Like, what if you did "@account.send(some_action)" but the user set "some_action" to "destroy". You'd be in trouble.